# Как сделать отправку письма с новым паролем в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Для создании авторизации использовал **artisan**:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Полез смотреть контроллеры, чтобы найти как **Larvel** отправляет ссылку на почту пользователя. И наткнулся ( и застрял ) тут ( `trait SendsPasswordResetEmails` ):

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Не понимаю дальше, как и откуда подтягивается шаблон письма, и сама отправка письма?

Не понятно, от кого наследоваться или какой метод подправить.

Comment: Не понял суть проблемы, вы хотите переделать метод чтобы он вместо отправки ссылки на восстановление отправлял на почту пароль?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan подправил вопрос. Так корректно делать? И подскажите, если я переопределяю метод экспортированного класса, то надо перепрописывать пространства имён?

Comment: @doox911 если Вы нашли подходящее решение, то, возможно, Вам стоит опубликовать его в поле для ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределил класс ( [источник](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-in-laravel--cms-30046) ):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller {

use ResetsPasswords;

protected $redirectTo = '/user';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function resetPassword($user, $password) {

    $mailobject = new \stdClass();
    $mailobject->password = $password;
    $mailobject->sender = $user->name;
    $mailobject->receiver = $user->name;

    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    Mail::to( $user->email )->send( new Mailer ( $mailobject ) );
}

}
```